# Reverse engineering or Auto-Generations of Entities in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, reverse-engineering

I usually work with SF2, and with Doctrine, Entities can be generated automatically and if you build the schema in a Soft like MySQL Workbench you can do Reverse Engineering.

I'm new to Laravel so there is a way to do these both things? I would use Laravel because I've to do a very little project, but I didn't want to write all this code for what we call "Migrations", seems very boring no?

So there is a way to generate this stuff in laravel? Maybe I've to use Doctrine in Laravel for that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to generate migration files from an existing mysql database you can use a Laravel package called XCMer / larry-four-generator. Apart from reverse engineering it has a bunch of other features.

> Larry Four is a Laravel 4 package offering advanced model and
>   migration generation functionality. Thanks to Larry you can quickly
>   jot down the data scheme for your idea in an easy DSL and genereate
>   migrations and models from it with just a single click. Larry can also
>   analyse your existing data scheme and generate some magic for you too.

Try the original best master branch 
https://github.com/XCMer/larry-four-generator/tree/master

or my Extended Models fork offering additional functionality  
https://github.com/XCMer/larry-four-generator/tree/Gadoma-extendedmodels

Comment: Finally it seems that larry can't generate models automatically, I've to write theses things called "input", I'm wrong ?

Migrations have been created but I care more about models

Comment: you are correct, but anyhow it's quick and easy to write the input - take a look https://github.com/XCMer/larry-four-generator#a-birds-eye-view

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell there is still no way to reverse a schema to migration files, using Laravel only. But you can:

1) Export your MySQL schema

```
mysqldump -u root -p --no-data dbname > schema.sql
```

2) Create a migration to use your schema

```
php artisan migration:make create_schema
```

3) Boot your full schema

```
class CreateSchema extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        $file = file_get_contents(app_path().'/database/data/full_schema.sql', true);

        DB::unprepared($file);
    }

    public function down()
    {
    }

}
```

4) After that, if you need to do any changes to your schema, just create new migrations and make your changes.

Not tested, but should work.