# how to create migration from existing database in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am new to `laravel`. i know command to create database from `laravel` migration.

I have already created database in `mysql`. so how can i convert migration from that database.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use Jeffrey Way's generator tool for Laravel 4, and do them by hand. It is a *very* useful tool. https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators (if you are using Laravel 5, use this package instead: https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended)

Or you could try out one of the following packages, they should convert your existing schema to Laravel migrations. I have not tried them, but have a look:

- https://github.com/adamkearsley/laravel-convert-migrations
- https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator

Also, read the following answer in another question, might be useful to you or others: [Reverse engineering or Auto-Generations of Entities in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271670/reverse-engineering-or-auto-generations-of-entities-in-laravel/20274636#20274636)

Comment: Just to add, here is another package that I currently use: https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator.  It is actively maintained and works great.

Comment: in addition   you can try  https://packagist.org/packages/gguney/rmigration  this package

Comment: the JefferyWay generators do not generate a migration from existing database. How come this is the accepted answer for this question?

Comment: I just used https://github.com/kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator and it worked well for me. I discovered it by going to https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator, noting it said only up to Laravel 5.4 was supported, reading the Github issues saying there was no support for 5.8, and in [this issue][https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator/issues/200] regarding support for Laravel 7, a link was posted to try another one.

Answer (score 7):

For modern versions of Laravel you should probably use a package like https://github.com/kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator

Comment: Do you know a package to create the seeders?

Comment: No sorry I didn't use any

Comment: I have just found [orangehill/iseed](https://github.com/orangehill/iseed) ... for future reference ;) It says it supports Laravel 9 (i never lose faith)

Answer (score 5):

If the accepted answer (at the time of editing this post) does not work for you, use this simple approach.

Check out this package by Kitloong is really easy to use.

https://github.com/kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator

After installation, just run something like this to export the migration to a location of your choice:

```
php artisan migrate:generate --path="path\to\existing\folder"
```

Example:

```
php artisan migrate:generate --path="C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_bs4\database\migrations\my_new_migrations"
```

You should end up with migrations created from the database and saved in the location you have specified.

You can omit the `--path` option and simply run

```
php artisan migrate:generate
```

This would export it to the default Laravel's migration folder (which is something I usually do not want).

**Be sure to follow the prompts. Sticking to the default is usually okay.**

Answer (score 3):

I quick wrote this python script to make migration files out of an existing database.

https://github.com/aljorhythm/sql-to-laravel-migrations

After set up, just do

```
python retrieve-and-convert.py
```

Comment: This solution also provides a PHP script.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution, to use online Laravel migration generator for your existing SQL table schema without installing any package. Just enter your SQL schema and get Laravel migration file.
Try: https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-migration-generator-online

Comment: This looks at first to be a useful tool. It immediately falls on its face using anything but the absolute most trivial and vanilla SQL. This is not a useful way to generate migrations for all but the absolutely most trivial case.

Comment: I'm not sure how old this tool is, but it is more trouble than it is worth. For the SQL create table definition of the field `\`status\` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1`, it was outputting a line like `$table->integer('status',1)->default(1)`. That second parameter to `integer()` is meant to be the auto-increments boolean. So I kept getting errors like `there can be only one auto column`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

[Migrations Generator](https://github.com/oscarafdev/migrations-generator).It's for Laravel, 4, 5, 6, 7, but I don't know if it is for Laravel 8

Comment: (09-2020) fails on a fresh Laravel 8 install. Which is a pity.

Comment: Just added Laravel 8 support, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using Doctrine 2 in your project instead of Eloquent that has reverse engineering built in.