# Some package to generate models in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, package

I have a database (SQL) and made their relationships are about 30 tables, I wonder if there is a package that generates the data of the database and I believe the models with their relationships in laravel 5.1

Sorry, my English is basic and I have to use a translator.

Comment: Are you looking to generate dummy data for those tables? If so, take a look at here: [Database Testing and Mocking](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database-testing#writing-factories). Also, have a look at the [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) library and a [tutorial](http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-faker-tutorial) on how to use it.

Comment: No, I can not explain in english well :( 
I need something to generate models and relationships in my database, already created, I have my .sql file.
Only in each model must be added the relationship in order to use it well,

Answer (score 0):

What you meant to say is "Reverse engineer" and seems like this is a duplicated question, however, you can find the answer in this question [Reverse engineering or Auto-Generations of Entities in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271670/reverse-engineering-or-auto-generations-of-entities-in-laravel), if you need more details because of your language barrier, don't hesitate to ask in this same thread.

You can also use this online tool laravelsd.com as well, you got to make your work twice, but at least you can design your db schema visually and download it when you get it done.